# Postgres: how to explicitly assign offset to a time without knowing time of year or server timezone setting

Tags: postgresql, time, timezone

How do I do I explicitly assign a timezone by name to a time (type) agnostic of the server's timezone, my location and without personally knowing the current daylight savings offset of the target timezone?

For context, the follow-on question I'll answer (and don't need help with the comparison to now() or localtime) is, "Regardless of my server's timezone, how do I know if the New York stock exchange is open if I know it closes at 1600 US Eastern time, regardless of the time of year (and daylight savings time)?"

The two problems are: (1) I don't know the current daylight savings offset and (2) I don't know what timezone the server is set to nor where the query will be run. Thanks in advance for forgoing the lecture about not having found the answer already.

Examples which are all incorrect:

```
select

    -- these solve the problem of not knowing the current offset but require knowledge of the local server's timezone setting

    timezone('US/Eastern','16:00:00'::time without time zone)
    --12:00:00.000000 -04:00
    --Incorrect: resulting timezone is correct but time is incorrect due to the implicit assumption the server is set to UTC (which it happens to be)
    
    ,timezone('UTC', timezone('US/Eastern','16:00:00'::time without time zone))
    --16:00:00.000000 +00:00
    --Incorrect: time value is right but the timezone is not represented as US/Eastern, again due to implicit UTC timezone
    
    -- these don't require knowledge of the server's timezone but require knowledge of the current offset in New York (which changes)

    ,'16:00:00.0 -04:00'::time with time zone
    -- and...
    ,timezone('US/Eastern', '16:00:00.0 -04:00'::time with time zone)
    --16:00:00.000000 -04:00
    --does not assume server timezone
    --Perfect except that both require foreknowledge of the current offset (so still useless, and the latter is duplicate effort)
```

Perhaps my question should be, how do I query Postgres's timezone database (by timezone name) and apply it to a time without timezone? Something wild like...

```
select '16:00:00.0'::time with offset (select utc_offset from pg_timezone_names where name='US/Eastern')
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves the two problems. It does not assume a server's timezone and it converts the "time without time zone" to a "time with timezone" differently depending on the time of year.

```
select timezone('US/Eastern', (select '16:00:00'::time without time zone - (select utc_offset from pg_timezone_names where name='US/Eastern')::interval)::time);
```

(correct) result: 16:00:00.000000 -04:00

ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-timezone-names.html

Ultimately solving my own problem:

```
select
    *
    ,case when time_eastern < close_time and time_eastern >= open_time then true else false end as is_open
    -- ...same as...
    ,case when now()::time with time zone < close_time and now()::time with time zone >= open_time then true else false end as is_open
from(
    -- 18:10:06.612792 -04:00, 16:00:00.000000 -04:00, 08:00:00.000000 -04:00, false
    select
        timezone('US/Eastern',now()::time) as time_eastern
        ,timezone('US/Eastern', (select '16:00:00'::time without time zone - (select utc_offset from pg_timezone_names where name='US/Eastern')::interval)::time) as close_time
        ,timezone('US/Eastern', (select '08:00:00'::time without time zone - (select utc_offset from pg_timezone_names where name='US/Eastern')::interval)::time) as open_time
)a
```

[image]